# JavaScript to check if string has at least three characters that are in another variable

Tags: javascript, string, character, var, indexof

I have a variable `activeUserName` and a variable `manager1`.

How can I check if `activeUserName` contains at least three characters, that are in `manager1`? (The position of those characters doesn't matter)

For example in the following case, it should return true, because the characters 'J', 'o' and 'e' are inside `manager1`.

```
var activeUserName = "JohnDoe100";
var manager1 = "JYZALoe999";
```

Right now I'm using the indexOf method and only look at characters in certain positions which is why I want to change that:

```
if (isEditor == false){
    if (((activeUserName.indexOf(manager1.charAt(0)) !== -1)  && (activeUserName.indexOf(manager1.charAt(2)) !== -1)) || (activeUserName.indexOf(manager1.charAt(4)) !== -1)){
        // doSth();
    } else if (((activeUserName.indexOf(manager2.charAt(0)) !== -1)  && (activeUserName.indexOf(manager2.charAt(2)) !== -1)) || (activeUserName.indexOf(manager2.charAt(4)) !== -1)){
        // doSth();
    } else {
        // doSth();
    }
}
```

I read about Regex, but I'm not sure if this can be applied here.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Combining [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you can trasform **activeUserName** in array and filter each char against the string **manager1**:

```js
var activeUserName = "JohnDoe100";
var manager1 = "JYZALoe999";

var howMany = activeUserName.split('').filter(function(e, i, a) {
    return (manager1.indexOf(e) != -1);
}).length;

console.log('The number of chars in common is: ' + howMany);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var activeUserName = "JohnDoe100";
    var manager1 = "JYZALoe999";
    const arr1 = [...activeUserName];
    const arr2 = [...manager1];
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
      if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) !== -1) count++;
    }
if(count >= 3)
  console.log(`string b 3 same values of string b`);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this approach is better, because we dont have to create a new array with split('')

```js
 var activeUserName = "JohnDoe100";
        var manager1 = "JYZALoe999";
        let count = ""
        for (let letter of activeUserName) {
            if (manager1.indexOf(letter) > -1 && status.indexOf(letter) == -1)
                count = count + letter
        }
console.log('Characters in common',count);
console.log('Length',count.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple conditions associated with the question like two occurrences of the same character should be counted as 1 or 2, should uppercase and lowercase character be treated as same or not, etc. I'd just leave this below code-snippet so that you get the gist of the final solution. Any condition on top of that, you can add it yourself.

```js
var activeUserName = "JohnDoe100";
var manager1 = "JYZALoe999";

let count = 0;

[...activeUserName].forEach(char1 => {
    [...manager1].forEach(char2 => {
        // add all your conditions here
        if(char1 === char2)
            count++;
    });
});

console.log(count);
```

The above code will output the number of characters which are common in both the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Split the check-string in an array from chars. Iterate through it if a char is contained in the str and sum this.

```js
var activeUserName = "JohnDoe100";
var manager1 = "JYZALoe999";


function check3Chars(str, check) {
    let count = 0;
    check.split('').forEach( char => {
        if (str.indexOf(char)!=-1) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    return count>=3;
};

console.log(check3Chars(activeUserName, manager1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code (ES5-compatible version). It should be more performant than other answers because it stops after 3 characters are found:

```js
var activeUserName = "JohnDoe100";
var manager1 = "JYZALoe999";

var matchedCharacters = [];
var activeUserNameArray = activeUserName.split('');
for (var i = 0; i < activeUserNameArray.length && matchedCharacters.length < 3; i++) {
  if (
    manager1.indexOf(activeUserNameArray[i]) > -1 // check if both strings include the character
    && matchedCharacters.indexOf(activeUserNameArray[i]) === -1 // exclude duplicates, you can remove this condition if you want to count duplicates
  ) {
    matchedCharacters.push(activeUserNameArray[i]);
  }
}

console.log(matchedCharacters.length);
if (matchedCharacters.length >= 3) {
  // the strings have at least 3 common characters
} else {
  // the strings have less than 3 common characters
}
```

Here is an ES6 version:

```js
const activeUserName = "JohnDoe100";
const manager1 = "JYZALoe999";

const matchedCharacters = [];
for (const char of activeUserName) {
  if (matchedCharacters.length >= 3) break;
  if (
    manager1.includes(char) // check if both strings include the character
    && !matchedCharacters.includes(char) // exclude duplicates, you can remove this condition if you want to count duplicates
  ) {
    matchedCharacters.push(char);
  }
}

console.log(matchedCharacters.length);

if (matchedCharacters.length >= 3) {
  // the strings have at least 3 common characters
} else {
  // the strings have less than 3 common characters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```js
// Format the string for easier comparison checking
const prepareString = (str) => str.split("").map((str) => str.toLowerCase());

export function similarCharacters(subject, test) {
  // Prepared subject string
  const left = prepareString(subject);

  // Prepared test string
  const right = prepareString(test);
  // Map over the subject with a number as the initial value, this will be our count
  return left.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    // acc is the current count value
    // curr is the current letter from the subject

    // If the right string has an occurrence of the current letter add 1 to the counter
    if (right.indexOf(curr) > -1) {
      return acc + 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, 0 /* our initial counter */);
}
```

**Unit test**

```js
describe("similarCharacters", () => {
  it.each([
    ["hello", "yellow", 4],
    ["JYZALoe999", "JohnDoe100", 3]
  ])("%s and %s have %p similar characters", (left, right, expected) => {
    expect(similarCharacters(left, right)).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

For your use case:

```js
const activeUserName = "JohnDoe100";
const manager1 = "JYZALoe999";

const similarCount = similarCharacters(manager1, activeUserName)
if(similarCount >= 3){
 // do something
}
```

CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-tree-ni8xu?file=/src/similarCharacters.js

Answer (score 1):

There are already some great answers, just wanted to join the party with a one liner that is not too hacky or unreadable.

```js
const a = "JohnDoe100";
const b = "JYZALoe999";

const total = [...b].reduce((count, char) => count + (a.includes(char) ? 1 : 0), 0);
```

It does have the benefit of not creating additional variables except for the `total` which is what you actually need.

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

### Use For loop with break and Use includes()

> To be **clean**, make a function that will do the job.

> To be **efficent** use `break` when you find 3 match chars.

Prefer **not** to use `var`, use `const` and `let`.

```
const areStringsMatchCharsMoreThen2 = (stringA, stringB) => {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < stringB.length; i++) {
    if (count === 3) break;
    if (stringA.includes(stringB.charAt(i))) count++;
  }
  return count === 3;
}
```

```js
const activeUser = "JohnDoe100";
const manager = "JYZALoe999";

const areStringsMatchCharsMoreThen2 = (stringA, stringB) => {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < stringB.length; i++) {
    if (count === 3) break;
    if (stringA.includes(stringB.charAt(i))) count++;
  }
  return count === 3;
}

console.log(areStringsMatchCharsMoreThen2(activeUser, manager));
console.log(areStringsMatchCharsMoreThen2('ABC', 'def'));
```